# Risk-neutral price of $H=e^{X_T^1+X_T^3}$

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, risk-neutral-measure, asset-pricing

Let $B=(B_t^1,B_t^2,B_t^3)$ a $\mathbb R^3$-valued Brownian motion. 
Let $r_t$ (risk free rate) be bounded and deterministic.
Let consider the DISCOUNTED market 
$$d\overline X_t^1=\frac52dt+2dB_t^1-dB_t^2-dB_t^3$$
$$d\overline X_t^2=7dt+2dB_t^1+2dB_t^2-10dB_t^3$$
$$d\overline X_t^3=\frac72dt+4dB_t^1-3dB_t^2+dB_t^3$$
I have already found that the market is arbitrage free.

I would like to find the risk-neutral price of the following claim:$$H=e^{X_T^1+ X_T^3}$$ (note: here the $X_T^1,X_T^3$ are not discounted) but i'm stack.
Any help please?

Comment: Are there 3 different $X_t$ processes? In your notation it seems the same process.

Comment: Also what are the $B$s at the end of each equation?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw yes sorry, now I edit it

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw don't you have any suggestion?

Comment: why not to use montecarlo to compute the price??

Comment: I don't understand how those dynamics are discounted. Normally, when you discount, you rebase by the money market account, i.e. $\bar{X}_t=X_t/B_t$, which usually has dynamics $dB_t=rB_tdt$ where $r$ is the interest rate. So I would have expected to see some term of type $f(t,X_t)dt$ in your equations. I don't understand how those were derived. Are you sure they are **discounted** dynamics?